# ReactJS - How to fix regex error for email validation?

Tags: reactjs, regex, validation, email, eslint

In react app, I am using regex to check email format. Actually its working fine but there is a `CodeQL` error like `This part of the regular expression may cause exponential backtracking on strings containing many repetitions of '+'.`

In /index.js,

```
const emailRegex = RegExp(/^[\w-_+]+([.-]?[\w-_+]+)*@[\w-_+]+([.-]?[\w-_+]+)*(\.[\w-_+]{2,})+$/)
if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
  setError("Invalid email")
}
```

If I try to add `\` to fix then will get an `eslint` warnings. Please suggest me the answer which works in both cases.

Comment: Not a solution to this problem, but I would suggest existing library to validate email address. Something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did that:

```
 var emailRegex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        if (!emailRegex .test(email)) {
        setError("Invalid email")
        }
```